# Exercise on cyclic code, parity check matrix and encoding

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $C$ be the linear code over $\mathbb{F}_2$ with generator matrix
>   $$G=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&1&1&0\\1&0&0&-1&0&1\\0&0&-1&0&1&-1\end{bmatrix}$$
>   (a) verify if $C$ is a cyclic code
>
> (b) find the minimum distance of $C$
>
> (c) encode the vector $(1,-1,0)\in\mathbb{F}_2^3$

**(a)**

$G$ has not a cyclic form, so we have to check by hand if $C$ is cyclic, ie we have to show that given a codeword $c$, if $c\in C$ then also $c[1]\in C$, where $c[1]$ is obtained from $c$ by a shifting of one position:

$c\in C$ iff $c=\sum_{i=1}^3a_ir_i=(a_2,a_1,a_3,a_1+a_2,a_1+a_3,a_2+a_3)$

with $a_i\in\mathbb{F}_2$ and $r_i$ rows of $G$.

Show that $c[1]=(a_2+a_3,a_2,a_1,a_3,a_1+a_2,a_1+a_3)=\sum_{i=1}^3b_ir_i$ for suitable $b_i\in\mathbb{F}_2$.

$\begin{cases}
b_2=a_2+a_3\\
b_1=a_2\\
b_3=a_1\\
b_1+b_2=a_3+a_2\\
b_1+b_3=a_1+a_2\\
b_2+b_3=a_1+a_3
\end{cases}\ 
\begin{cases}
b_1=a_2=0\\
b_2=a_3\\
b_3=a_1
\end{cases}$

a solution exists, so $c[1]\in C$ and other shifts belongs to $C$, then $C$ is cyclic.

**(b)**

$G=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&1&1&0\\1&0&0&1&0&1\\0&0&1&0&1&1\end{bmatrix}$ because $-1=+1\ mod\ 2$

$G\ '=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&1&0&1\\0&1&0&1&1&0\\0&0&1&0&1&1\end{bmatrix}$ standard form (permutation of rows 2 and 3)

$H\ '=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&1&0&0\\0&1&1&0&1&0\\1&0&1&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$ control matrix of $G\ '$

$H=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&1&0&1&0\\1&1&0&1&0&0\\1&0&1&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$
parity check matrix (permutation of rows 2 and 3)

minimum distance $d=3$ (minimum number of dependent columns in $H$)

correction capacity $t=\lfloor\frac{d-1}{2}\rfloor=1$.

**(c)**

$x=(1,-1,0)=(1,1,0)\in\mathbb{F}_2^3$

to encode $x$ it is enough to compute $xG=(110011)$

---

Since I'm new to the topic, I would like to know if the exercise is correct, and in particular:

1. if I permute rows in the generator matrix, when I find the parity check matrix should I permute the same rows or the columns?
2. is it possibile to permute both rows and columns of the generator matrix?

Comment: Please ask *one* question at a time.

Comment: maybe I can split it in 2 questions, first with points (a) to (c), second with (d) and (e).